# Standardize axis as multiple graphs generated from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a seemingly simple problem of standardizing and labeling my axis on a series of graphs I am creating from a DataFrame. This dataframe contains a column with a sort of ID and each row contains a value for x and a value for y. I am generating a separate graph for each ID; however, I would like a standard axis across all of these graphs. Here is my code:

```
  groups = data.groupby('Pedigree')
  for Pedigree,group in groups: 
        group.plot(x='EnvironmentalIndex',y='GrainYield',marker='o',linestyle='',color ='white',label=Pedigree)
        plt.plot([0,250],[0,250],linestyle = 'dashed',color='black')
        x = group.EnvironmentalIndex
        y = group.GrainYield
        z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
        p = np.poly1d(z)
        q = sum(y)/len(y)
        plt.plot(x,p(x),color='green')
        plt.text(25,220,'Stability=%.6f'%(z[0]))
        plt.text(25,205,'Mean Yield=%.6f'%(q))
```

I know there is an axes function in Matplotlib, but I can't get the formatting right so that it plays well with the for loop. I have tried inserting a
        group.axes()
inside of the for loop but I get the error that the list object is not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by `standard` having the same ticks, there are different ways of doing this, one is, if you don't have a lot of plots, create a subplot that shares the same x-axis,

```
no_rows = len(data.groupby('Pedigree'))
no_columns = 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(no_rows, no_columns, sharex = True)
ax = ax.reshape(-1)
count = 0

for Pedigree,group in groups: 
    ...
    q = sum(y)/len(y)
    ax[count].plot(x,p(x),color='green')
    ax[count].text(25,220,'Stability=%.6f'%(z[0]))
    ax[count].text(25,205,'Mean Yield=%.6f'%(q))
    count+=1
```

Only the xticks from the bottom plot will be applied, you can also define a different number of columns but make sure `no_rows * no_columns >= # of plots`.

Comment: This works, but since I have 21 plots it results in a very crammed image window. Is there a way to increase the size of the overall image so its not as crammed with plots?